# Large Image uploading error Using Base 64 string Alarmofire Swift / .Net Services

Tags: swift, apache, wcf, iis, alamofire

I have have a strange problem for uploading images the following code works well with small images but when i try to upload large size images if fails with following error 
413 Request Entity Too Large ginx/1.6.0
I am using WCF .Net Services with IIS 6/7.

I am creating base 64 string of the image using following method :

```
func getBase64StringFromImage(anImage: UIImage, enhanceUpto:CGFloat) -> String{

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage, enhanceUpto)
    let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    //print(base64String)
    return base64String
}
```

And then the following service call :

```
if aSenderImageView1.image != nil{
    base64ImageString1 = sABase64ImagetoString.getBase64StringFromImage(aSenderImageView1.image!, enhanceUpto: 1.0)
}
if base64ImageString1.length > 0 {
      finalParamDict = ["Attach":base64ImageString1,"FileName":"Image1.jpeg"]
}
finalParamDict["Email"] = self.emailTxtField.text!
finalParamDict["Mobile"] = mobileNo
finalParamDict["NameEn"] = Defaults["customerName"].string!
finalParamDict["POBox"] = self.addressTxtField.text!
finalParamDict["ID"] = customerQID
finalParamDict["ServiceID"] = serviceID
finalParamDict["VAL1"] = gender

Alamofire.request(.POST,serverUrl ,headers:serviceHeaders,parameters:finalParamDict, encoding:.JSON)
                .responseJSON{
                    response in
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
}
```

This is the response for larger images mostly larger then 1MB.

```
Optional(<html>

<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>

<body bgcolor="white">

<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>

<hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center>

</body>

</html>

)
```

Comment: Sounds like your web service has a size limit

Comment: You could find out what the size limit is, and compress the image if it's too big

Comment: Aaron, the android version is working fine with large images, looks like iOS issue only.

Comment: The server is the one with an error. Nothing in your request code is limiting the size or creating the HTTP error.

Comment: Yes you are right, but what to check then, the webservice working fine as well !

Comment: Step through the web service code and figure out WHY it is a returning a 413

Comment: Actually they can not debug as well because the response is coming in middle of mobile and server. May be apache or iis